# PHP Unknown datetime format from JSON

Tags: php, json, datetime

I'm eceiving an unknown datetime format from a JSON file:

```
"expectedStartTime":1431469800000
```

anyone recognize this format, and can guide me into how to convert it to "YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s" format?

Comment: Probably milliseconds from the epoch

Comment: so it should be `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", ($expectedStartTime/1000))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expecting it is a timestamp in milliseconds it should work like this:

```
$json = '{"expectedStartTime":1431469800000}';

$arr = json_decode($json,true);

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $arr['expectedStartTime']/1000);
```

The given value will output:

```
2015-05-13 00:30:00
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is only correct in the UTC+2 timezone.  I guess you live in Europe somewhere.  If the OP needs to write it as UTC to a database, they should probably use the DateTime object or make sure their PHP timezone is UTC inside their application.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Java style unix timestamp which is miliseconds from the epoch. You can divide by 1000 and treat it as a normal Unix timestamp like this.

```
$expectedStart = new DateTime("@" . ($time/1000));
print $expectedStart->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```